# Adjoint of an operator question.

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let T be a normal operator. Prove that $\|T\|^{2n}=\|TT^*\|^n$

Has it got something to do with $\|T\|=\|T^*\|$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you don't need $T$ to be normal. Your equality holds for any $T$.

Note first that $\|T^2\|=\|T^*T\|$: this follows from
$$
\langle \|Tx\|^2=\langle Tx,Tx\rangle=\langle T^*Tx,x\rangle\leq\|T^*T\|\,\|x\|^2,
$$
so $\|T\|^2\leq\|T^*T\|\leq\|T^*\|\,\|T\|$. We immediately get $\|T\|\leq\|T^*\|$. As this reasoning applies also to $T^*$, we get $\|T\|=\|T^*\|$ and $\|T\|^2=\|T^*T\|$. In particular
$$
\|T\|^2=\|T^*\|^2=\|(T^*)^*T^*\|=\|TT^*\|.
$$
Taking $n^{\rm th}$ powers, we get
$$
\|T\|^{2n}=\|TT^*\|^n,\ \ \ n\in\mathbb N.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For a normal operator use the fact that

$$\|T^{*}T\|=\|T^2\|.$$

(Since $\langle T^*Tx,x\rangle=\|Tx\|^2=\langle TT^*x,x\rangle$).

Then use  induction.

Comment: Why is that true?

Comment: @user108605: ok- let me provide a proof by editing my answer.

Comment: Please: MathJax is not the work of primitive cave men.  I changed $< T^*Tx,x>=\|Tx\|^2=< TT^*x,x>$ to $\langle T^*Tx,x\rangle=\|Tx\|^2=\langle TT^*x,x\rangle$. ${}\qquad{}$